# Bash array of strings

Tags: arrays, bash, snmp

I have a bash script which gathers snmp information and searches it for key phrases to alert on.

I use an snmp command to output logs from a network device, this is an example of the code and the original output-

```
/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c public $HOST .1.3.6.1.3.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255

SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255.27.228.239.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.251 = STRING: "Host link down. (port: 1)"
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255.27.228.239.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.252 = STRING: "Host link up. (port: 1, speed: 8 Gbps, number of loop ID(s):"
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255.27.228.239.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.253 = STRING: "A scrub-vdisk job was started. (vdisk: test, SN: 00c0ff1bf86d0000a6c09c5600000000)"
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255.27.228.239.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.254 = STRING: "A scrub-vdisk job completed. No errors were found. (vdisk: test, SN: 00c0ff1bf86d0000a6c09c5600000000)"
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255.27.228.239.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.255 = STRING: "Host link down. (port: 1)"
```

In my bash script I create an array from this and strip out the bumph at the start-

```
declare -a LOG=($(/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c public $HOST $OID | cut -d" " -f 4-))
```

This creates this-

```
"Host link down. (port: 1)"
"Host link up. (port: 1, speed: 8 Gbps, number of loop ID(s):"
"A scrub-vdisk job was started. (vdisk: test, SN: 00c0ff1bf86d0000a6c09c5600000000)"
"A scrub-vdisk job completed. No errors were found. (vdisk: test, SN: 00c0ff1bf86d0000a6c09c5600000000)"
"Host link down. (port: 1)"
```

My problem is that this array treats every word as a separate entry, so my actual output is this-

```
"Host 
link 
down. 
(port: 
1)"
```

So whenever I search for individual words it works fine, but when I search for phrases it breaks.

Ideally what I would like it to do is store each line of text as its own entry in the array, like this-

```
declare -a LOG=('"Host link down. (port: 1)"' '"Host link up. (port: 1, speed: 8 Gbps, number of loop ID(s):"') etc
```

I'm just not sure how to manipulate the original declare line to do this...

Here is all my code-

```
HOST="10.10.10.10"
OID=".1.3.6.1.3.94.1.11.1.9.32.128.0.192.255"
declare -a CRITICAL=('errors' 'An event was reported by a disk drive')

declare -a LOG=($(/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c public $HOST $OID | cut -d" " -f 4-))

for RESULT in `echo ${LOG[*]}`
    do
    for WORD in `echo ${CRITICAL[*]}`
        do
            case "$RESULT" in
                *$WORD*)
                    OUTPUT+="$RESULT -CRITICAL "
                    ;;
                *)
                    OUTPUT+="$RESULT "
            esac    

        done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the IFS ([internal field separator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)) variable to `\n` it should achieve what you want.

```
IFS=$'\n' declare -a LOG=($(/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c public $HOST $OID | cut -d" " -f 4-))
```

There is also an issue with the way you are iterating through the results. try the following so you don't split the individual lines into words (which the * operator will do).

```
for RESULT in "${LOG[@]}"
    do
    for WORD in "${CRITICAL[@]}"
        do
```

Comment: Hi, cheers for your reply- I tried this but it has now joined all of the lines together in one big single arry entry... Also, it has stripped out all of the letter 'n's out of the text!

Comment: I made an error (omitting the `$`), can you try again?

Comment: Ah yes this is getting very close- the only problem is that it now adds every single word to one entry in the array, instead of a separate entry for each line. But it is able to search for strings. Any further thoughts on getting the lines right?